# Node.js debugger not working

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm, ejs, nodeclipse

I have express.js with ejs templating.

I can see that for first request, debugger stops at break point.

But after ejs serves page on browser, any further requests never stops at break point.

I tried lot of things in frustation -> webstorm, eclipse, node-inspector,etc

Is there some config for ejs or experss that I am missing?

Even console.log is not printing anything. I know flow works for sure.

Comment: Please show the actual code in question.  It could be caching, branching, etc... but who knows without seeing what code you're actually talking about.

Comment: its just too much code to paste here..so didnt

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was my bad.

I was trying to debug js in public folder which is client side js.

So i have debug using chrome developer tools instead of server side debugging.